# Blocked sites even using tor.

Tags: onion-services

Keep getting "this site is blocked". Im using tor, all the config options are correct according to the FAQ. Even the blocked sites message tells me to use tor, which makes no sense considering I'm using tor. Any ideas?

Comment: The site is detecting Tor wrong or you haven't set up Tor correctly. Are you using Tor Browser?

Answer (score 1):

The site blocking issue can be these kinds in your situation:

- The website is blocked too in the exitnode's location. Maybe it will be the same ISP or AS as yours.
- You're leaking a DNS requests to your ISP servers, and these servers are giving you the "it's blocked" page address instead of the website you want. After that you're trying to connect to the wrong address through Tor. Of course, it will be "blocked"
- Your browser is not using Tor, actually. There are some glitchy situations, when browsers are just ignoring or bypassing the proxy settings. In Firefox a FoxyProxy extension is a right thing to try - it uses to fix such a problems too.

Comment: Like Alexey Vesnin said, the webpage might be blacklisting exit nodes. But I suggest using a web proxy to browse the site while on Tor Browser. But while they circumvent blocks, web proxies are rather limit the website functionality (e.g. trying to sign in a website from web proxy doesn't work), and will probably not make you anonymous (which might not be a problem since you're already using Tor). But if these concern you, try a VPN over Tor instead of a web proxy.